# Am I taxable in Germany even I did not live there?

Tags: germany, taxes, tax-treaties, financial

Last year I received some bonus payments from my previous employer (I worked in Germany the year before and lived/worked Germany until the end of that tax year).

The bonus was deposited in my German bank account at the beginning of last year, meaning that for my taxes purposes it has to be declared in the 2020 tax year even if I did not live/work in Germany at that time.

Now, in an online software which I use to prepare my German tax returns, it computes that I owe a hefty amount of German tax. The rationale is that it counts my last year income (indicated as foreign income for Germany) to determined the tax rate they will apply to my German taxable income (bonus payment), the software indicates that this is determined by the "progression clause (Progressionsvorbehalt)".

I can see that this is expected and fair for a person working or living, partially or fully, in Germany, however, I wonder if it does applies for a person who did not spent a single day living/working that taxable year in Germany.

I currently live outside of EU.

Comment: Does `Last year I received some bonus payments from my previous employer (I worked in Germany the year before` mean **Last year (2020) I received some bonus payments from my previous employer (I worked in Germany the year before (2019)**? So the payment actually recieved in 2020 was for work done in 2019? If yes, this would be a question for a tax advisor to determine which year counts.

Comment: Should it be 2020, that may be based on January 2020 (€ 10000*12=€120000). Since that was the only earning in 2020, the tax refund for 2020 would return a lot of the paid tax since the yearly earning is €10000 instead of the estimated €120000.

Comment: If you have not done so, submit a tax for 2020 with the bonus income as sole earning. Both (2019+2020) tax returns should then balance out.

Comment: @MarkJohnson that was not the sole earning for 2020, during that year I work in another country.

Comment: But the work in the other country would be taxed there and not in Germany. Details would depend on any double tax treaties between the two countries.

Comment: @MarkJohnson: "But the work in the other country would be taxed there and not in Germany." I believe they are describing taxation rules where a nonresident is taxed only on their income from that country, but at a tax rate that is determined based on their worldwide income (the income that the rate is based on matters for jurisdictions that have progressive tax brackets). I think this is a fairly common setup for taxation of nonresidents of a country or nonresidents of a state. I do not know if Germany is like this, but it seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @user102008 That seems to be the case when the person is a German resident. In this case the OP was not a German resident in 2020. [Grundzüge der Besteuerung ausländischer Einkünfte - Einkommensteuerfreistellung mit Progressionsvorbehalt](https://www.steuernetz.de/lexikon/grundzuege-der-besteuerung-auslaendischer-einkuenfte):

Comment: @user102008 **Income tax exemption with progression proviso** *... **But**: If Germany is your country of residence, your gross foreign income will be included in the progression proviso when calculating the tax rate for your remaining income (Section 32b (1) No. 3 EStG), which results in a higher tax burden for this.*

Comment: @MarkJohnson: [Here](https://www.finanzamt-rente-im-ausland.de/export/sites/fmria/de/.galleries/formulare/Formulare-2020-Einkommensteuer/ESt-1C_2020-RiA-komplett.pdf) is the German tax form for limited tax liability (i.e. for nonresidents). Line 45 asks you to enter the income not subject to German tax, as part of applying the progression proviso. Page 3 of the instructions (page 7 in PDF), top part, right column, also talks about the progression provision in assessing the tax rate. I don't read German, but it seems that it does apply to nonresidents.

Comment: @user102008 **This is something that a tax advisor should be asked about**. If I'm reading this correctly it seems to apply only for *the citizens of an EU / EEA State and have their place of residence or habitual abode in the territory of one of these states*. Line 42 asks this would the be set to 0 (for the OP).

Comment: @MarkJohnson I cannot find that provision at line 42, could you quote the sentence?

Comment: @user102008 Ich bin Arbeitnehmer und Staatsangehöriger eines EU- / EWR-Staates, habe im Hoheitsgebiet eines dieser Staaten meinen Wohnsitz oder gewöhnlichen Aufenthalt und beantrage die Veranlagung zur Einkommensteuer (§ 50 Abs. 2 Satz 2 Nr. 4 Buchst. b EStG).

Comment: @user102008 do you now where can I find a german tax advisor online, is there anything like a H&R Block in Germany?

Answer (score 3):

It seems correct. The money is Germany-sourced income since it is work income (bonus) from work performed in Germany (even though the money was received in a different year than when the work was performed). Therefore, it should be taxable in Germany no matter where you live.

It seems that your complaint is that the fact that it is taxable in 2020 instead of 2019 (due to your company paying that money to you after the new year) caused you to have to pay more tax since your tax rate in 2020 happens to be higher than in 2019. Well, that's just bad luck. It could just as well have worked the other way if circumstances had been different -- i.e. if your tax rate in 2020 happened to be lower than in 2019, then the fact that the money is taxable in 2020 instead of 2019 would have caused you to pay less tax.